# How show horizontal scrolling of UICollectionView in Objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

Currently i am using this code :

```
[_collectionVwForTopScroll registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DrinksCollectionViewCell" bundle:nil] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"DrinksCollectionViewCell"];

_collectionVwForTopScroll.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UICollectionViewFlowLayout *collectionViewFlowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
[collectionViewFlowLayout setScrollDirection:UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal];
_collectionVwForTopScroll.collectionViewLayout = collectionViewFlowLayout;

_collectionVwForTopScroll.delegate = self;
_collectionVwForTopScroll.dataSource = self;
```

- But itemForIndexpath Notcalled .

Comment: Is `_collectionVwForTopScroll` visible? Does it have room for Cells? If no to either of those, the methods won't be called. It would help if you show your `numberOfSectionsInCollectionView` and `numberOfItemsInSection` and `cellForItemAtIndexPath` methods.

Answer (score 0):

The method

```
- (__kindof UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

will be called if you have:

- Added `UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol
- Minimum amount (1) of sections and items in section

Check out those methods